# how to create nesting Components in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have created one demo for creating nesting component in vue.js.

but it is not working.

See below code...

```js
Vue.component('component-a', {
  template: '<div><span>Hi</span><slot></slot></div>',
  components: {
    'component-b': {
      template: '<div>Hello</div>'
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<component-a>
  <component-b></component-b>
  </component-a>
  </div>
```

But **component-b** is not rendering.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare `component-b` in `component-a`. [Local registering of components make them only accessible withing the components they are registered (declared), **not globally, not even to their children**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html).

And, in your code, `component-b` is being used by the root component, not by `component-a`. `component-a`'s template is:

```
<div><span>Hi</span><slot></slot></div>
```

There's no use of `component-b` there. With:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <component-a>
    <component-b></component-b>
  </component-a>
</div>
```

You do are using `component-b` **in the root's** template. But it was not registered nowhere the root component can see.

You have some alternatives.

#### Move the registration to the root, where it is used:

```js
Vue.component('component-a', {
  template: '<div><span>Hi</span><slot></slot></div>'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'component-b': {
      template: '<div>Hello</div>'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component-a>
    <component-b></component-b>
  </component-a>
</div>
```

#### Register it globally, like `component-a`

```js
Vue.component('component-a', {
  template: '<div><span>Hi</span><slot></slot></div>',
});
Vue.component('component-b', {
  template: '<div>Hello</div>'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component-a>
    <component-b></component-b>
  </component-a>
</div>
```

#### Or use it inside `component-a` instead of the root and move the slot (changes semantics)

```js
Vue.component('component-a', {
  template: '<div><span>Hi</span><component-b><slot></slot></component-b></div>',
  components: {
    'component-b': {
      template: '<div><slot></slot></div>'
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component-a>
    <div>Hello</div>
  </component-a>
</div>
```

Comment: One more question is that can I add some restriction in registration of component-b that it must be children of component-a?

like: Vue.component('component-b', {
  template: '<div>Hello</div>',
  parent: 'component-a'
});

Comment: Hm... unfortunatelly, no, Vue still doesn't support that. The closest it gets to that is registering it locally, but, as we found out, If we do that, we can't use `component-b` in the root, not even if it is inside a `<slot>`...

Answer (score 0):

You need to register `component-a` ***and*** `component-b` to your Vue instance if you want to call them globally.

The local instanciation of `component-b` (in `component-a`) is never called in the `component-a`'s template.

So do something like this, it will solve your problem:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});

Vue.component({
    'component-a': {
         template: '<div><span>Hi</span><slot></slot></div>',
    },
    'component-b': {
        template: '<div>Hello</div>',
    }
});
```